# How to Show Date Format in Webgrid in MVC3 as "MM/dd/yyyy"

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

How do I show Date Format in Webgrid in MVC3 as "MM/dd/yyyy"?

Comment: Could you show us the code you have so far in the view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you haven't shown any code so, im going to answer what i have got you can try

```
grid.Column("Date",format:@<text> @item.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</text>)
```

Answer (score 1):

PLease don't use magic format in ToString. You can set cultury in server or client. and use Date.ToShortDate()