# How to use Currency & String Formatting in ASP.NET WebGrid helper?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, string, webgrid

How to use Currency & String Formatting in ASP.NET WebGrid?

#### Actual Code

```
    @allConsignmentGrid.GetHtml(
                       tableStyle: "table table-bordered table-hover",
                        columns: allConsignmentGrid.Columns(
                            allConsignmentGrid.Column("courier_booked_date".ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "Date"),
                            allConsignmentGrid.Column("client_id", "Client"),
                            allConsignmentGrid.Column("consignment_no", "Con"),
..
..
```

**Error in**

```
allConsignmentGrid.Column("courier_booked_date".ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"), "Date"),
```

I know, it is wrong. How to use formating in WebGrid in ASP.NET.

---

I come across following official doc, I don't find my solution.

1. [How to use ASP.NET WebGrid](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-aspnet-web-pages-2/displaying-data)
2. [ASP.NET WebGrid Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid(v=vs.111).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution :

```
allConsignmentGrid.Column("courier_booked_date", format:@<text>@item.whateverYourPropertyName.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")</text>)
```

Comment: Just checked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9044940/how-to-show-date-format-in-webgrid-in-mvc3-as-mm-dd-yyyy